# Creating / Running Sqoop Job in Shell Action Using Oozie

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, oozie, hive-metastore

I'm trying to run a Sqoop job in Shell script using Oozie.
Please note, that i'm using cdh5 in my local machine (vm with 12G of RAM), and HUE to build the workflow.

**I created a Sqoop job that extracts data from Mysql to HDFS, in a shell script. And I run it using Oozie :**

```
sqoop job --create testmetastore --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:16000/sqoop -- import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db --table EMPLOYEE --username root --password cloudera --target-dir hdfs://localhost:8020/user/cloudera/EMPLOYEES -m 1
```

**The Job has been created (I can find it when I do a list cmd, see bellow):**

```
sqoop job --list --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:16000/sqoop
```

[sqoop job --list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIDbl.png)

**I even executed the job from my terminal and it works (see cmd below):**

```
sqoop job --meta-connect jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:16000/sqoop --exec testmetastore
```

**I deleted the last imported folder, and tried to re-execute the job again but this time in Oozie. It gives an error (see below):**

```
18/12/23 10:47:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: counters are unavailable. To get this information, 
18/12/23 10:47:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: you will need to enable the completed job store on 
18/12/23 10:47:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: the jobtracker with:
18/12/23 10:47:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.active = true
18/12/23 10:47:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.hours = 1
18/12/23 10:47:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: A jobtracker restart is required for these settings
18/12/23 10:47:06 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: to take effect.
18/12/23 10:47:06 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Import job failed!
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

**Here is the sqoop-site.xml:**

```
          <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>If true, Sqoop will connect to a local metastore
      for job management when no other metastore arguments are
      provided.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url</name>
    <value>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:16000</value>
    <description>The connect string to use when connecting to a
      job-management metastore. If unspecified, uses ~/.sqoop/.
      You can specify a different path here.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.username</name>
    <value>SA</value>
    <description>The username to bind to the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.password</name>
    <value></value>
    <description>The password to bind to the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.record.password</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>If true, allow saved passwords in the metastore.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.server.location</name>
    <value>/tmp/sqoop-metastore/shared.db</value>
    <description>Path to the shared metastore database files.
    If this is not set, it will be placed in ~/.sqoop/.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.server.port</name>
    <value>16000</value>
    <description>Port that this metastore should listen on.
    </description>
  </property>
```

**Here is the workflow.xml:**

```
<workflow-app name="MyWorkflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="shell-7268"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="shell-7268">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>/user/cloudera/sqpexec.sh</exec>
        <file>/user/cloudera/sqpexec.sh#sqpexec.sh</file>
        <file>/user/cloudera/sqoop-site.xml#sqoop-site.xml</file>
          <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

**Here is a view from HUE:**
[workflow in HUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVE7W.png)

The reason why i'm trying to run a sqoop job in shell script from Oozie, is that I want to create a sqoop job that remenbers the last value imported so that it can increment the table, and then schedule it using Oozie. So this is just a first step test!

Can you please help ?
Thanks,

Comment: are you using a small setup? How big your cluster is? If job is handing for a long time, it means your cluster size is not good enough. You can try the same by restarting your server and it may work. If possible share you workflow.xml file if you are using oozie to submit the job.

Comment: Can you please check the updates? Thanks,